# Как из list вытащить экземпляр класса в textBox

Tags: c#, winforms, классы, list

Нужно создать программу, генератор экземпляров класса Car по нажатию кнопки (данные вводятся в соответствующие поля самим пользователем). Вычитал, что одним из способов, является добавление экземпляра класса в list, далее экземпляр перезаписывается и снова добавляется следующим элементом в list. Добавил, теперь хочу что бы все элементы list, а точнее вся вводима информация пользователем, выводились в textbox6. Не знаю как это сделать.

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>(); //Для хранения экхемпляров класса Car

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Car car = new Car(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text), textBox4.Text); //экземпляр
    cars.Add(car); //добавляем в list
    }

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox6.Text = cars(?)// :(
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cars.Add(new Car(textBox1.Text, int.Parse(textBox2.Text), int.Parse(textBox3.Text), textBox4.Text););
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox6.Text = cars[int.Parse(textBox7.Text)].ToString();
    //Вам нужно будет создать textBox7, который будет обозначать индекс машины, которую нужно получить
}
```

В Car добавьте:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
   result.Append("Название: " + Model + "\n");
   result.Append("Какое-то значение: " + FirstNum + "\n");
   result.Append("Ещё какое-то значение: " + SecondNum + "\n");
   result.Append("Имя водителя: " + Name + "\n");
   return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Очень странная работа с SB, давайте оптимизирую? Если вы не против.